# How to select multiple classes in css?

Tags: css

Is there any shorter way to select all these things using only once the id `#load` ?

```
#load p,
#load h1,
#load h2,
#load h3,
#load h4,
#load h5,
#load h6 {
  font-size: 80%;
  margin:2%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always add a class to the elements:

```
<h1 class="myclass"></h1>
<h2 class="myclass"></h2>
etc...

And then select them all with that class:

#load .myclass {
  font-size: 80%;
  margin:2%;
}
```

---

If you use SASS (or any CSS preprocessor) then it would look something like this:

```
#load {
  p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: 80%;
    margin: 2%;
  }
}
```

SASS needs to be installed on the server, which will then compile the code to pure CSS. The result will be the same thing you posted in the question.

---

Also, I'm adding this as an option,
there is the **matching** CSS selector:

```
#load :-moz-any(p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) { /* firefox 4+*/
  font-size: 80%;
  margin:2%;
}

#load :-webkit-any(p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) { /* chrome 15+, safari 5+, opera 15+ */
  font-size: 80%;
  margin:2%;
}
```

There is no support for the [matching selector](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-matches-pseudo) by IE/Edge

Comment: The SASS code doesnt work for me. Do i need a css file or a sass ?

Comment: @DamianToczek It's a preprocessor, you need to install it on the server. The code is then compiled to pure CSS. When it's done, the result will be the same code you posted in the question. -- If you can't install it, then the best thing would be to add a class to all elements you want to add this to. -- The matching selector is not supported in IE/Edge. -- I've added this info in the answer.

Comment: Using a class for this will take way more letters than this css :) 75 headers.

Answer (score 1):

if they are always going to be direct children of `#load`, you could do

```
#load > * {
  font-size: 80%;
  margin: 2%;
}
```

but keep in mind that these rules will apply to ANY immediate child of `#load`

otherwise you could also opt to give those all a class, like `load-child` for example

```
#load .load-child {
  font-size: 80%;
  margin: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS certain properties inherit the properties of encapsulating html elements (unless manually overriden). So this means that you could simply do:

```css
#load {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id=load>
  <p>hello from p</p>
  <h3>hello form h3</h3>
</div>
```

As you can see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) `font-size` is by default an inherited property. (this reference is CSS2 - I can't find the CSS3 one anywhere?)

So this means the requried `#load` css now encapsulates its children `h` and `p` elements.

*note I just put 40px for visibility in the example*.

https://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade is a good quick read on element inheritance but to summarise;

> Inheritance lets us declare properties on high-level elements and allows those properties to trickle down to all descendant elements. Only some properties are inherited by default, but inheritance can be forced with the inherit keyword.

Answer (score -1):

Not unless you want everything. You can get everything with `#load *`.